# F# Add element created in a for loop to a list

Tags: list, f#, tuples

I want to add an element to a list. The elements will be created inside of a for loop. What I currently have is

```
let MaxCubeVolume tpList = 
    let list1 = [] 
    printfn "%A" list1 
    for l,w,h in tpList do
        let vol = CubeVolume l w h 
        let list = vol::list1
        printfn "%A" list
```

Where list1 is the main list I am trying to add to, and list is what I am trying to use to add to that list. CubeVolume is working, it takes 3 floats and returns the volume of a cube. tpList is a list of tuples which contain 3 floats. Where I'm lost is how I add the vol to the main list?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

F# lists are immutable. You can't "change" them. You don't "add" elements to them. You can only create a *new* list out of the old one (but the old one remains unchanged and still available for use).

But this is the wrong frame of mind for functional programming. In functional programming you don't compute the result by repeatedly modifying data structures. Instead, you compose larger data structures out of smaller ones, or by using (and composing) primitive functions that do it for you.

In particular, if you have a list of, say, hypothetically, triples, and you have a function that can transform one such triple into, say, hypothetically, a number, and you'd like to make yourself a list of those numbers - that's a very well known primitive operation called `map`:

```
let tripleToNumber (l, w, h) = CubeVolume l w h
let list1 = List.map tripleToNumber tpList
```

Or you can specify the transforming function inline, without giving it a separate name:

```
let list1 = List.map (fun (l, w, h) -> CubeVolume l w h) tpList
```

And then you can use the `|>` operator to rearrange the parameters of `List.map`, just to make it look a bit nicer:

```
let list1 = tpList |> List.map (fun (l, w, h) -> CubeVolume l w h)
```

Or, alternatively, you can use F# list comprehensions, which are syntactic sugar: they're doing the same thing under the hood, but have a (arguably) better look:

```
let list1 = [for (l, w, h) in tpList -> CubeVolume l w h]
```

An important thing to note here that neither of the above snippets actually *change* any data in place. Both of them generate a new datum by transforming an old one.

Comment: Love how comprehensive this is, for a language basics question.

Comment: I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Fyodor's answer (which is pretty comprehensive), a general F# solution for what you've named your function (finding the maximum value of the result of a computation of a sequence) would be to compose the `map` and `max` functions.  These functions exist on the standard F# collection modules (`Seq`, `List`, and `Array`), and you can chain them together using the `|>` operator:

```ml
let maxCubeVolume tpList = 
    tpList |> Seq.map (fun (l,w,h) -> CubeVolume l w h) |> Seq.max
```

You could also compose them together using the `>>` operator instead:

```ml
List.map (fun (l,w,h) -> CubeVolume l w h) >> List.max
```

There's also a built-in function `maxBy` on the standard F# collections that returns the element in the collection which has the maximum value for a given function.  This would return the cube itself (the one with the maximum volume) rather than the computed value for the volume. Here's an example using `Seq` (the most general of the F# collection types):

```ml
let maxCubeVolume tpList = 
    tpList |> Seq.maxBy (fun (l,w,h) -> CubeVolume l w h)
```